# How to remove the last part of a string url in PHP

Tags: php, string, url

I need to parse a google sheet url string in php, removing the last part of it. Example:

`$string = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxx`

Then i need to remove the 'edit#gid=xxxxxxx' part of the string, like so:

`$string_parsed = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
$string_parsed = explode('/','https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxx');
array_pop($string_parsed);
echo implode('/', $string_parsed);

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it worked. But you need to edit the answer and change your first variable to $url